# Stored procedure update to remove duplicates

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_SAP_Mat_InsertWhereUse]
    (@cust varchar(10),
     @materials varchar(15),
     @Comp varchar(20),
     @qty int)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS ((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM [SAP_Mat_WhereUse] 
                WHERE Material = @materials AND Component = @Comp 
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 0))
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS ((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM [SAP_Mat_WhereUse] 
                    WHERE Material = @materials AND Component = @Comp 
                      AND Quantity =  @qty 
                    HAVNG COUNT(*) = 0))
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [SAP_Mat_WhereUse] 
            SET Quantity =  @qty 
            WHERE Material = @materials AND Component = @Comp
        END
    END
    ELSE IF ((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM [SAP_Mat_WhereUse] 
              WHERE Material = @materials AND Component = @Comp 
                AND Quantity = @qty) = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SAP_Mat_WhereUse (Customer, Material, Component, Quantity) 
        VALUES (@cust, @materials, @Comp, @qty)
    END
```

This is my database data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlD3d.png

If there are any duplicated material + duplicated component, then the stored procedure should automatically remove the duplicated rows and update the quantity of the primary row. And duplicated material + non-duplicated component shall  remain.

Therefore, I can remove the duplicate but the quantity count remain the same, is there any modification need to be made on my existing stored procedure? Please help

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. I believe your tags are wrong

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try to fix the data first and then changing the procedure only to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. For example, the following code should do that (but please, test it first):

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT Customer
          ,Material   
          ,Component 
          ,SUM(ISNULL(quantity, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY  Customer, Material, Component) AS [OveralQty]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  Customer, Material, Component ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [RowID]
    FROM [SAP_Mat_WhereUse]
)
SELECT *
INTO #DataSource
FROM DataSource
WHERE [RowID] = 1;

TRUNCATE TABLE [SAP_Mat_WhereUse];

INSERT INTO [SAP_Mat_WhereUse]
SELECT *
FROM #DataSource;
```

Then, you can change your routine like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_SAP_Mat_InsertWhereUse]
(@cust varchar(10),
 @materials varchar(15),
 @Comp varchar(20),
 @qty int) 
 AS
 BEGIN;

SET NOCOUNT ON;



IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM [SAP_Mat_WhereUse] 
    WHERE Material = @materials 
        AND Component = @Comp 
        AND Customer = @cust
)   
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [SAP_Mat_WhereUse] 
        SET Quantity =  @qty 
        WHERE Material = @materials 
            AND Component = @Comp
            AND Customer = @cust;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SAP_Mat_WhereUse (Customer, Material, Component, Quantity) 
        VALUES (@cust, @materials, @Comp, @qty);
    END

END
```

Of course, depending on your data size, you may not be able to fix the data at one and prefer to do it gradually.

You can apply the same fix, but for particular rows:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT Customer
          ,Material   
          ,Component 
          ,SUM(ISNULL(quantity, 0)) OVER () AS [OveralQty]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [RowID]
    FROM [SAP_Mat_WhereUse]
    WHERE Customer = @cust
        AND Material = @materials 
        AND Component  = @comp
)
SELECT *
INTO #DataSource
FROM DataSource
WHERE [RowID] = 1;

DELETE FROM [SAP_Mat_WhereUse]
WHERE Customer = @cust
    AND Material = @materials 
    AND Component  = @comp 

INSERT INTO [SAP_Mat_WhereUse]
SELECT Customer
      ,Material   
      ,Component 
      ,[OveralQty] + qty 
FROM #DataSource;
```

or (because there are many variants to do this) - you can just `sum(quantity)` in your current code, store it in a variable and then add it.